# Sum amount inside DataTable with same ID

Tags: c#, datatable

For example

```
| ID | Amt |  
------------
|  A |  3  |
|  A |  2  |
|  B |  2  |
```

Result

```
| ID | Amt |  
------------
|  A |  5  |
|  B |  2  |
```

My current strategy is always check if same ID already exist before inserting. Just wondering if it's possible to just insert everything and sum same ID after that.

Comment: You can use `GroupBy` and `Sum` extension methods from `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: My current strategy is by checking if same ID already exist before inserting new row.

Comment: dt = dt.Select("SELECT SUM(Amt), ID GROUP BY ID, Amt);

Comment: It is not clear if you talk about a table on the database (where the operation should be executed using sql logic or if you talk about a DataTable NET object. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Steve: I'm referring to .NET DataTable. Not SQL table.

Comment: There is nothing AFAIK in the DataTable that allows to automatically SUM the duplicates while you insert them (and thus changing the INSERT in an UPDATE). However setting the PrimaryKey property and executing a search before adding is simple.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing AFAIK in the DataTable that allows to automatically SUM the rows with the same key value (duplicates) while you add them to the DataTable (and thus changing the INSERT op in an UPDATE op).

However after setting the PrimaryKey property and executing a search before the Add operation is simple.  If you want to increment the field value of  a an existing DataRow in your DataTable object then you need to retrieve that row and then increment its value.

For example, suppose you have this kind of table:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(System.String));
dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(System.Int32));
dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {dt.Columns["ID"]};

dt.Rows.Add("A", "10");
dt.Rows.Add("B", "20");

DataRow[] found = dt.Select("ID='A'");
if(found.Length == 1)
{
    int value = found[0].Field<int>("Amount");
    found[0].SetField("Amount", value + 10);
}
```

More complex is the situation if you already have a DataTable that contains duplicate rows and you want to Group them by the key column and Sum the Amount column. In this case I think you need to build a new DataTable creating the informations needed using the GroupBy extension

(Same table as before, but no PrimaryKey of course)

```
dt.Rows.Add("A", 10);
dt.Rows.Add("A", 20);
dt.Rows.Add("B", 20);

var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
       .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("ID"))
       .Select(g => new { ID = g.Key, Amount = g.Sum(z => z.Field<int>("Amount")) });

DataTable t2 = dt.Clone();
foreach (var grp in result)
    t2.Rows.Add(grp.ID, grp.Amount);
```

And now the T2 table contains only the non duplicate rows with the Amount summed. Of course, at this point you still need the first approach if you want to add an existing row.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    var result= (from a in table.AsEnumerable()
                 group a by new{id= a.Field<string>("ID")} into g
                  select new {
                      ID=g.Key.id,
                      Amt=g.Sum(x=>x.Field<int>("Amt"))
                    });
```

Updated for .net table.

Comment: .NET DataTable, not SQL table.

Comment: so you wanna use Linq for that.?